# User class threw exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: python

I'm trying the below code and it is failing with out of bound exception

```
list = [a, b, c]

if not x == 'y':
   list.insert(len(list), "x")
```

I tried below code:
`list.insert(len(list)-1, "x")`

this is not working
It would be appreciated if anyone could explain why this is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: `list = [a, b, c] if not x == 'y': list.insert(len(list), "x")` What is this supposed to do? Are `list = [a, b, c]` and `if not x == 'y': list.insert(len(list), "x")` supposed to be on different lines?

Comment: yes they need to be in separate lines

Comment: Why do you have a Java exception in Python?

Comment: maybe he's using JPython

Comment: @Prem clarify your question please.

Comment: this is python script used for running scala code  which submits spark applications

Comment: Anyways, if you're trying to append to a list, why not use the `.append` method instead of `insert`?

Comment: not familiar with the context in which you're running python, but my suspicion is your distribution of python does not support inserting beyond the length of the list. So you should just do an `.append("x")`

Comment: append takes only one argument i have to pass 2

Comment: ?? if you are trying to insert at the back of the list, that is equivalent to appending. Besides, the function you use decides how many arguments you need to pass and not the other way round of "I have to pass 2 arguments therefore i must use this function"

Comment: okay i tried with .append('x") it is giving the same out of bound exception

Comment: my only recommendation now is to re-ask your question and specify where and how you are running this script, tagging the relevant communities (i assume its scala and spark?)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the built-in list type with the first line.

Try renaming your list to something else.

```py
my_list = [a, b, c]

if not x == 'y':
   my_list.insert(len(my_list), "x")
```

Comment: tried this it is still giving out of bound exception